# What is the HOPOPT protocol and how does socket() work?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I'm messing with sockets in C and this protocol continues to show up, I couldn't find anything about it, so what is it used for? What's the difference between HOPOPT and IP?

Also i'm don't get why the last argument of the socket() function should be 0. According to the man page:

> The protocol specifies a particular protocol to be used with the socket. Normally only a single protocol exists to support a particular socket type within a given protocol family, in which case protocol can be specified as 0. However, it is possible that many protocols may exist, in which case a particular protocol must be specified in this manner. The protocol number to use is specific to the “communication domain” in which communication is to take place; see protocols(5). See getprotoent(3) on how to map protocol name strings to protocol numbers.

As far as I understand setting the last argument to 0 will let the standard library to decide which protocol to use but in which case would one use a number other than 0?

Comment: "in which case would one use a number other than 0?" >> _However, it is possible that many protocols may exist, in which case a particular protocol must be specified in this manner._

Comment: @SouravGhosh, I'd like to see a real example, that's what I meant

Answer (score 2):

HOPOPT is the acronym of the [Hop-by-Hop IPv6 extension header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Hop-by-hop_options_and_destination_options). It is a header that allows to add even more options to an IPv6 packet. It is normal that IPv6 packets include this header.

`socket()` is the system call that BSD and others (Linux et al.) provide to create a new socket, that is the internal representation of a network connection. When creating a new socket, the desired protocol must be specified: TCP, UDP, etc., which may go over IPv4, IPv6, etc.

The paragraph that you are citing explains that one or many protocols may exist for each socket type.

If only one exists, the `protocol` argument must be zero. For instance, `SOCK_STREAM` sockets are only implemented by TCP:

```
int sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
```

If more exist, than you must specify which protocol in particular you want to use. For example, the `SOCK_SEQPACKET` type can be implemented with the SCTP protocol:

```
int sk = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_SEQPACKET, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

So, in conclusion:

- If you want to create a socket, choose what protocol to use, for instance TCP over IPv4.
- HOPOPT is totally normal in an IPv6 packet. If you see it appear in your traces, because you created an IPv6 socket (using `AF_INET6`), it is OK.